# NullPointerException while getting an Image

Tags: java, image, swing

I am having trouble setting images in my newest game. When I call the method `getImage(String)`, and I get the Image like so:

```
Image head = getImage("Torso_model_01.png");
```

I get the following error message:

```
Err: java.lang.NullPointerException
  At PB2Main.Body(Body.java : 27)
  ...
```

and so on...

On [this tutorial](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J4b_CustomGraphics.html#zz-7), it explains how to get an image using ImageIcon like so:

```
String imgFile = "Images/" + img;
URL imgURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(imgFile);
ImageIcon imageIcon;
Image image;
 if(imgURL != null){
  imageIcon = new imageIcon(imgURL);
  image = imageIcon.getImage();
 }

 final Image anImage = image;
```

I made a method for this:

```
public URL getURL(String img){
  String imgFile = "Images/" + img;
  URL imgURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(imgFile);
  return imgURL;
}
```

Then I made a method called getImage(String)

```
public Image getImage(String img) {
  ImageIcon imageIcon;
  Image image;
  URL imgURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(getURL(img));
  if(imgURL != null){
   imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imgURL);
   image = imageIcon.getImage();
   return image;
  }
   System.err.println("Unable to Locate Image: " + imgURL);
}
```

Now, I have a class called `Body`.
In that class, I have a constructor:

```
public Body(float x, float y, String head, String torso){//atm this is just so i can                    get the image to actually draw on the screen
Image Head = debugger.getImage(head);// debugger doubles as a library and debugger
//i also can't have this class extend debugger otherwise it will create a window :/
// is that a glitch or something in Java? :L perhaps i just don't understand
// inheritance very well and what happens exactly when you inherit a class :(
Image Torso = debugger.getImage(torso);

 g2.drawImage(Head, canvas.geWidth()/ 2,canvas.getHeight()/2, null)// canvas: the window to  
 //draw to
 // can someone also quickly explain in their answer what an image observer is please?
 g2.drawImage(Torso, Head.getX() - 5, Head.getY() - 5, null);
}
```

The compiler gives me the following error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
At PlazmaBurst2.Body(Body.java: 37)

//the code it brings me to is line 1 in the constructor:
/* null: */ Image Head = debugger.getImage(img);
```

I don't understand where this NullPointerException is coming from. I did it exactly how they do it in the Custom Graphics Programming section of [the same site](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J4b_CustomGraphics.html#zz-7).

The code works fine if I just copy and paste the code, but not if I use the method `getImage(String)`.

Comment: The issue is you aren't giving the correct file path to the image. Where is the code being run from and where is the `Images` directory?

Comment: @vandale i don't need to specify where Images/: (the image) is because Im using Eclipse Luna Developer Build IDE, it gets all its resources in bin folder. Trust me, the problem is the Image being null, not a coding problem. if it were, using the code within the method would be useless.

Comment: Looking at your code I think you actually call `Image Head = debugger.setImage(head);` and not `Image Head = setImage(head);`.  As that exact lines causes an npe it looks like your `debugger` variable isn't initialized?

Comment: but that isnt the problem sir with all due respect; the problem is the Images being null, not the class being null; ;)

Comment: There are three different versions of what may be the problem in your text so it's a bit hard to guess what's going on.  It's probably best to add the full code to the relevant file(s) of ***exactly 1 version*** (once you say it npes on line 27, once on line 37 so I can only assume you're trying different things, and, just guessing, hitting different albeit related issues.

Comment: its all the same issue, the compile messages and the lines are examples of what comes up. It just has to do with those three things, the Images, setImage(), and null;

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer if `Image head = setImage("Torso_model_01.png");` NPEs ***whatever setImage() is a method of is null***.  Be it (implicitly) `this` or `debugger`, it's ***that object*** that is null.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Wow this post... I've come so far since this happened... Thanks for all the help though! I eventually find out that the problem was in placing the Images in the CLASSPATH environment (i.e. the .class files and then the folder IN that folder with the .class files) Now I use netbeans; I found out Eclipse is worse than I thought and Im beginning to LOVE netbeans now so YAY! I always wondered why Eclipse takes so long to compile and run the program!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is on line 3 of `getImage(String)`:

```
URL imgURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(getURL(img));
```

This should be changed to:

```
URL imgURL = getURL(img);
```